# What is wrong with it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've seen a lot of example for `wait` and `notify`, but still I have a problem.

```
public class Main(){
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        MyThread s = new MyThread();
        s.start();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        k();
    }

    public synchronized void k() {
        System.out.println("before wait");
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("do something after wait");
    }

    public synchronized void m() {
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
        notify();
    }
}
```

The only output I get when run the program is: `"before wait"`.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Any exceptions?

Comment: no , the output is only : "before wait"

Comment: I wonder that why people give minus to my question , without answering it !

Comment: Are you calling `MyThread.m()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: You are missing very important information in the question that's why. You should cleary tell what is your issue, not just that *something* is wrong.

Comment: You tell all the thread to wait, and never wake it up. Did you mean to call `m()` somewhere? We don't know what you're trying to do, which is why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: where should i call that ? David Frank

Comment: it 's because of that I am a beginner , I am sorry if it is simple question , but I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread you create in `main` invokes `MyThread#k()` which goes into a wait. At that point, that thread will do nothing else until it is awakened or interrupted. But the only place in your code where it could possibly be awakened is the `notify` in `MyThread#m()`. Since nothing in your program calls that method, the thread can never be awoken.

What you probably want is to add a call to `s.m()` right after `s.start()` in your main program. That way your main thread will execute the `notify` that's needed to wake up your thread.

Unfortunately, that's very unlikely to work. The problem is that `s.start()` causes your created thread to become ready to run, but it doesn't necessarily run immediately. It could well happen that your call to `s.m()` will complete before the created thread does anything. And then you'll still have exactly the same result as before, except that you'll see the integers 0..6 printed out before `before wait`. The `notify` will do nothing, because the child thread has not yet performed its `wait`. (And by the way, since both `MyThread#k()` and `MyThread#m()` are both synchronized, increasing your loop limit in `MyThread#m()` won't change a thing... the child thread won't be able to enter `MyThread#k()` while `MyThread#m()` is running. You could improve that by putting the `notify` in a sycnchronized block rather than making all of `MyThread#m()` synchronized.)

You can try to get around this by adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` before `s.m()` in your main program. That will almost certainly work because your main thread will yield execution, giving your JVM the opportunity to schedule the child thread for some useful work. By the time the main thread wakes out of its sleep and performs its `s.m()` call, the child will probably have executed its `wait` and you will then see your `do something after wait` message.

But that's still pretty crummy, because it still depends on scheduling events that you don't really have any control over. There's still no **guarantee** that the `wait` will happen before the `notify`.

This is why when using wait/notify you should generally arrange for there to be some sort of reliable test as to whether whatever you're waiting to be done has actually occurred. This should be a condition that, once it turns turns true, will remain true at least until the test has been subsequently performed. Then your typical wait loop looks something like this:

```
while (!isDone()) {
    synchronized(monitorObject) {
        try {
            monitorObject.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Putting the whole thing in a loop takes care of premature waking, e.g. due to InterruptedException.

If the required work has already occurred by the time this code is executed, no `wait` occurs, and the `notify` executed by the code that did the work was a no-op. Otherwise, this code waits, and the code completing the work will eventually do a `notify` which will wake this code up as required. Of course, it's critical that, at the time the `notify` is performed, the wait condition (`isDone()` above) be true and remain true at least until tested.

Here's a corrected version of your code that incorporates a proper wait loop. If you comment out the `Thread.sleep()` call, you will likely not see the `waiting` message, because the work will complete before the wait loop even starts. With the sleep included, you'll probably see the `waiting` message. But either way, the program will work properly.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    MyThread s = new MyThread();
    s.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s.m();
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        k();
    }

    private boolean done = false;

    public void k() {
        System.out.println("before wait");
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("waiting");
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("do something after wait");
    }

    public void m() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            done = true;
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're not calling your `m` method, so `notify` is never called, so your thread sleeps forever. You could call it in `main`, after the start, using `s.m()`:

```
MyThread s = new MyThread();
s.start();
s.m();
```

Maybe you should `sleep` for a little time before calling the `m` method, as it could run sooner than `k` in the thread:

```
s.start();
try {
    Thread.sleep(200);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // nothing to do
}
s.m();
```

Not closely related to the question, but a `throws` declaration in `main` is not very advisable, even a generated `printStackTrace` is better than throwing the exception away.

Comment: where I should call that?

Comment: now the answer is " 0 1 2 3 4 5 , before wait" why ?

Comment: It seems, the `m` method was called sooner than `k`. If your code is  the same as the one I have written, maybe you need to sleep for a bit before calling `m`.

Comment: why it happen ? it is more surprising that when i debug it , the output is different : " before wait , 0 1 2 3 4 5 , after wait" what is the difference?! @meskobalazs

Comment: I guess because this way the thread could have started, when you called `m`. Remember, `k` is running in another thread, `m` is run in the main thread. Updated my answer to mention this.

Comment: my code is exactly like your edit :"MyThread s = new MyThread();
  s.start();
  s.m();" @meskobalazs

Comment: it becomes true !tnx why it goes wrong without sleep ? how can m run sooner than k?

Comment: In one word, the answer is *concurrency*

Comment: but ..in run we only call k, and before wait we sysout something, still i can't understand how can concurrency happen here by this code..

Comment: The starting of the Thread (`s.start()`) has a small time cost (in the order of ns or ms tops), but the main thread can continue at once, this is the cause.